# Drupal 7 WYSIWYG module with latest ckeditor font change

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor, drupal-modules, wysiwyg

I want to change the default "Timesnewroman" font to "Verdana" / something else. I tried `config.font_style` and `config.font_names` in config.js but it didn't worked. Is there any workaround to change this settings.

Note: I'm using ckeditor plugin via Drupal 7 WYSIWYG module.

Comment: In the end it's either CSS or HTML `style` attributes that control the font. Have a look at the source generated by CKEditor to see how the fonts are handled. If it's css classes, you can just override them in your CSS. If it's embedded as HTML styles, you need to change them manually or by scripting. If 

I was you, I'd make and ACF rule to disallow styles, stop users from being able to select fonts and only use CSS. (If it's possible in drupal... I don't know so this is just a comment :))

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook in your template.php file

```
function THEMENAME_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) {
    if ($context['profile']->editor == 'ckeditor') {
        $settings['font_names'] = 'Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;Verdana';
        $settings['font_defaultLabel'] = 'Verdana';
    }
}
```

You also can add other settings for CKEditor